# Exif.js always returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, exif, exif-js

I'm currently developing a simple WEB Application that allows users to upload a photo.

That photo's EXIF GPS data is then supposed to be extracted to a variable that will then be used in a google maps widget, with a "pin" on the location of shooting. The idea is then generate a link for users to be able to share both the photo and the google maps widget on Forums.

The issue at the moment is in the use of the EXIF.js library.

I currently have a simple html page just to test/try this such library and the code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>EXIF</title>
</head>

<body>

    <img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" />

    <h1>Localização da foto</h1>
    <p id="info_model"></p>


    <script src="exif.js"></script>

    <script>

        window.onload=getExif;

        function getExif() {
            var imagem = document.getElementById("img1");

            var modelo = EXIF.getTag(imagem, "Model");

            document.getElementById("info_model").innerHTML = modelo;

        }

    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

The expected result should be for it to say: "iPhone 6S Plus"

The actual result is: "undefined"

I can confirm the photo used to test the code does in fact have valid EXIF

**New code as suggested:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>EXIF</title>
</head>

<body>

    <img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" />

    <h1>Modelo da câmara</h1>
    <p id="info_model"></p>


    <script src="exif.js"></script>

    <script>

        window.onload=getExif;

        function getExif() {
            var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
            EXIF.getData(img1, function() {

            var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");



            var modelo = document.getElementById("info_model");
            modelo.innerHTML = `${model}`;
            });
        }


    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `undefined` is what any `function` in Javascript returns *by default*  if you do not **explicitly** `return` something other.

Answer (score 1):

`getData` works *asynchronously* and as such, needs to be passed a **callback function**, which your code does not have. You can only call `getTag` after you've called `getData`.

See the example on

> https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js
>
> Start with calling the `EXIF.getData` function. You pass it an image as a parameter:
>
> - either an image from a `<img src="image.jpg">`
> - OR a user selected image in a `<input type="file">` element on your page.

```
function getExif() {
  var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  EXIF.getData(img1, function() {
    var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
    var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
    var makeAndModel = document.getElementById("makeAndModel");
    makeAndModel.innerHTML = `${make} ${model}`;
  });
}

window.onload = getExif;

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
<pre>Make and model: <span id="makeAndModel"></span></pre>
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" id="img1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've edited the code to my using case and now it doesn't return any value at all. I've edited my question with a "new code"

Comment: Check the code example in my answer to see it works.

Comment: *Note: The EXIF standard applies only to .jpg and .tiff images.* https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: It does indeed work with that picture but not with my picture...

Actually, the "new code" I posted also works with that picture as well... 

I don't know what the issue is with my picture as it does indeed have valid EXIF...

Comment: This website can perfectly read the EXIF of the photo I was using to test it:


http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi

Comment: PS: I've donwloaded this picture 

https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4867/30883801817_bf122bc498_o.jpg to my PC and now it can't read the EXIF...

So, it can read it if it's on a server but not if it's local?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be already solved, but I'd like to offer alternative solution using library [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr). It's new, maintained and actively developed library with focus on performance.

```js
<img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" />
<h1>Modelo da câmara</h1>
<p id="info_model"></p>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/exifr@2.1.3/index.js"></script>
<script>
    async function getExif() {
        var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
        let output = await exifr.parse(img)
        var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
        var modelo = document.getElementById("info_model");
        modelo.innerHTML = output.Model;
    }
</script>
```

The important part here is the async/await. The image is loaded asynchronously so you need to wait until it's loaded and parsed. This is similar to above mentioned callbacks but more modern.

You can check out the library's [playground](http://mutiny.cz/exifr/) and experiment with images and their output, or check out the .[repository and docs](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr)

[image]